# Split power between LEDs and PCB

Tags: power-supply

I'm designing a system that runs WS2182B signals down RS422 lines to LED strips powered elsewhere.

Where I'm stuck is that it makes sense to use the 5V power for the LEDs to power the RS422 receiver board since they're all 5V systems, but I can't figure out what connector(s) I would use. Ideally it would be something that just connects the power more or less directly to the LEDs and lets the tiny amount of power the PCB will need just draw off of that.

Is something like that even a good idea?

Comment: Are you asking about the connector from your power supply to the led strips or from the led strips to a small pcb? The former is normally either soldered wires or a clip on type connector typical of led strips. The latter can be a soldered wire or it could be a wire tap. Or use a splitter for the led strip connector. Actually it may be easier if you picture or draw what you are thinking.

Comment: everything that conducts well can do the job in that case… a chocblock, twist the wires and solder them, there is no hard requirement in that case.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question. Are you asking about a connector type of if you can use power in parallel?

Comment: @ScienceGeyser, thank you yes exactly that. I couldn't really figure out the phrasing, but yes a connector to power the board and LEDs in parallel would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm designing a system that runs WS2182B signals down RS422 lines to LED strips powered elsewhere.

that seems like a good idea.

> but I can't figure out what connector(s) I would use.

If the led strip has a connector I would use that, if not maybe make a PCB with notches in the side and solder that to the strip.

solder the power wires to the strip too